# How does Vue.js set observers in computed properties?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

If I have a computed property that looks like this:

```
computed: {
  greeting() {
    const state = this.$store.state;
    if (state.name === 'Joe') {
      return 'Hey, Joe';
    } else {
      return 'Hello, ' + state.name;
    }
  }
}
```

What object(s) is Vue going to set an observer on? `this.$store.state` or `state.name` or both? Asking because:

- I want to make sure this Vue instance isn't listening for *any and all* changes to the Vuex store -- it seems like that could degrade performance in a large application.
- I have a business requirement to set some computed properties via props, and I'm having a hard time getting them to be reactive.
- I'm just plain curious.

Comment: This should tickle your fancy. https://www.skyronic.com/blog/vuejs-internals-computed-properties

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the `this.$store.state` and `this.$store.state.name` properties are reactive (they should be), then Vue will observe changes to these properties and re-evaluate `greeting` when the values of these properties change.

No other properties will be observed.

This will cause `greeting` to be re-evaluated:

```
this.$store.state.name = 'foo';
this.$store.state = bar();
```

This will *not* cause `greeting` to be re-evaluated:

```
this.$store.state.foo = 'foo';
this.$store.state.a.b.c = 'bar';
this.$store.apple = 'pink lady';
```